# How can i select date older than today in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have the following code that outputs the past 30 days entries from phpmyadmin SQL database. It does work and shows my past 30 days entries, but it also displays today's date entries, which I don't want. Is there any way, we could get all the past 30 days entries, excluding today's date?
Hers's the code

```
("SELECT * FROM products  WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following query:-

```
SELECT * FROM products  WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```